# How to not select blank text in tkinter text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, selection, text-widget

Is there any way to not select blank text in tkinter.

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root , width = 65 , height = 20 , font = "consolas 14")
text.pack()

text.insert('1.0' , "This is the first line.\n\nThis is the third line.\n\nThis is the fifth line.")

mainloop()
```

Here when I select a few lines, the blank text at the end of each line also gets selected.

[image]

What I want that the blank text should not get selected.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really an "area" being selected: the Text object contains (and
selects) *characters*, not *areas*. It's important to distinguish the
characters being selected, and their representation on the screen.

The last character in every line is a newline `'\n'` (that's actually what
defines a *line*). When you move the mouse beyond the dot `'.'` (to the right),
you're including the newline in your selection.

Now, the Text widget normally inverts foreground and background colors to
indicate that a character is selected, but the newline is not explictly drawn
as a character, it's actually invisible (apart from the fact that the text
jumps to the following line). These blank areas that bother you are just the
Text widget's way of telling you that you've selected the newline character,
and I don't think you can change this display behaviour.

Comment: @juao, Yes, I actually meant blank text by 'blank area', maybe I should make an edit.

Comment: Are you interested in what's being *selected* ? or what's being *displayed* ? It's unclear from your question.

Comment: @juao: I'm actually interested on both. I don't want blank text to get selected, also I don't want to show the user as if the blank text is being selected.

Comment: Your text has newlines because it has multiple lines. I don't think the Text widget has an option to not select newlines. Why not just select everything and then do `s.replace('\n', '')` ?

Comment: If I use that, all the text will stay in a single line and there will be no newlines.

Comment: If you decide to keep the newlines in your selection, the Text object will give you visual feedback by highlighting the rest of the line, and I don't think you can change that.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to not select blank text in tkinter.

No, that is how tkinter visually represents the selection of a newline character.

The only way to do it would be to replace tkinter's default selection mechanism to not select newlines, but then when you get the selection you won't get the newlines. I think users would be very surprised by that.

Comment: `The only way to do it would be to replace tkinter's default selection mechanism to not select newlines`. Hello @BryanOakley, could you please provide some code in your answer that shows how I can implement this suggestion?

Comment: @Lenovo360: no, that's a lot of work. I don't have the time to implement a solution for you. You just have to set up bindings for button clicks and drags, and manually add the `sel` tag to everything but the newlines. If you do that, when you copy and paste the data you will get one long string instead of multiple lines since you would be explicitly ignoring the newlines. There would be no way to know where one line ended and the next began.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I wasn't experienced enough in tkinter to understand what you said, but now I have followed your suggestion and it works perfectly. Upvoted.